# Relationship between Fisher Test and Student Test

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test

When performing linear regression with one variable, one can compute Fisher's test with value $F$, and derive Student's test $T=\sqrt{F}$.

When there is more than one variable, the relationship $T=\sqrt{F}$ no longer holds. Is there a relationship between $F$ and the different Student tests $T_i$ (one for each variable)? Perhaps a system of equations?

EDIT :

I am referring to the F test in Excel's linear regression report:

[image]

*Note : crossposted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548804/relationship-between-fisher-test-and-student-test) with no answer.*

Comment: What "Fisher's test" are you referring to?

Comment: @utobi I am reffering to the F test which is run by Excel when performing linear regression.

Comment: and by "more than one variable" do you mean more than one predictor?

Comment: Yes, by variable I mean explanatory variable / predictor.

Comment: the relation between $t$ and $F$ is always true no matter what is the number of predictors, as long as you test a single predictor. If you want to test jointly more than one predictor, you have to switch to an $F$ or a Wald test.

Comment: In the above example, we have $F=23.46$, $T_1=\mbox{t-Stat(hours)}=6.18$, $T_2=\mbox{t-Stat(prep_exams)}=-0.66$. I would like to know if there is a set of equations linking $F,T_1,T_2$. In the case with only one predictor, $T_1=\sqrt{F}$. This no longer holds in this context.

Comment: the answer to your question is obviously no.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is what you mean, but the $T^2$ [Hotelling test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution) is a generalization of the $t$-test for multivariate normal means.

Suppose that $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$, where the number of dimensions is $p$. The number of observations is $n$. The test statistic is $$T = n (\bar{X} - \mu)' \hat{\Sigma}^{-1} (\bar{X} - \mu)$$, which using SVD decomposition for $\hat{\Sigma}$ is, suppose that $S$ is a diagonal matrix of the eigen-values and $U$ is the eigenvectors of $\hat{\Sigma}$. You obtain

$$ T= n (U(\bar{X}  -\mu))' S^{-1} U(\bar{X} - \mu),$$ which can be viewed as sum of squared $t$-statistics.

The statistic is related to $F$ distribution by $\frac{n-p}{p(n-1)}T \sim F_{p, n-p}$.